# Редактировать несколько строк одновременно в VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Импортирую List в бд и хочу просто удалить "new Product" перед каждой строкой(одновременно). Как это можно реализовать в студии?

у меня в листе есть объекты вида

```
        new Weapon("a", 505, 332, 7, 1.5),
        new Weapon("b", 436, 286, 7, 1.5),
        new Weapon("c", 454, 226, 6, 1.5),
        new Weapon("d", 392, 195, 6, 1.5),
```

я просто хочу сделать копи-паст в таблицу и одновременно из всех строк убрать new Weapon. Видел где-то хот-кей на эту тему).

Хочу получить

```
("a", 505, 332, 7, 1.5),
            ("b", 436, 286, 7, 1.5),
            ("c", 454, 226, 6, 1.5),
            ("d", 392, 195, 6, 1.5)
```

Comment: Не понятня суть вопроса... Если ты хочешь класс сохранить в бд, то смотри в сторону сериалзации...

Comment: @iluxa1810 конкретизировал вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте ещё вариант, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: @Monk добавил...

Comment: Сделайте обычную замену `new Weapon` на пустоту. Замену можно делать только в выделенном тексте, а потому не сломается ничего лишнего.

Comment: Зажми Alt+Shift и выделяй стрелочками или мышкой.

Comment: Спасибо. Оба способа рабочие!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать alt+shift чтобы выделить несколько строк. 
Либо выделить участок кода и заменить new Weapon на пустую строку с помощью ctrl+h